# Looking for a library of XSLT to create SVG charts

Tags: xml, xslt, svg, fxsl

I'm looking for a library of XSLT to create SVG charts.  I need pie charts, bar charts, line charts, all the usual suspects.  I would hope for a reasonably simple DTD or Schema for the input files.

**Edit**: I have the raw data for the charts and a mechanism to convert it into what ever XML is necessary for the XSLT library.

Comment: Good question (+1). FXSL provides some support needed for such transformations -e.g. trigonometric functions. If you could provide a small (as small as possible) example of a source XML document and the desired output, with a description of how the input contributes to the output, I may try to create such a transformation. :)

Comment: A simple example of what I am looking for is here... http://www.carto.net/svg/samples/xslt/

Comment: Have you tried a news group? http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/svg-developers/ Great question!

Comment: It seems to me a charting component that can export to SVG would be more common.

Comment: See the update to my answer. IMPORTANT: Don't try to access topxml.com without a good malware protection tool!

Comment: I've got a GREAT malware protection tool... OSX!

Answer (score 2):

Try [SvgCharts4Xsl](http://franklinefrancis.github.com/SvgCharts4Xsl). Works with XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dpawson.co.uk/graph2svg/ was recently mentioned on the XSL mailing list. Uses XSLT 2.0 however.

Comment: No problem using 2.0, it is what I prefer.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT transforms *between* XML representations. So what are you looking to transform *from* ? It sounds like (perhaps) you need an SVG library such as [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/). Note that using Batik means you can write to a Java graphics component, and then output that as SVG (as opposed to JPG, PNG etc.)

Comment: I have data from a database that I can arrange however into XML, say columns and rows.  I want an XSLT to apply that will convert my table data into a chart.

Comment: Looks like Batik is a java library, not an XSLT library.

Comment: It is indeed. But I refer you to the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: SVG is an XML representation, and I want to use XSLT to transform between my XML representation (that I am willing to adapt) and an SVG representation.

Answer (score 0):

**You may try [FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)** -- while it doesn't directly support SVG, it provides some functions necessary for some transformations -- for example trigonometric functions.

**Update**: There are a [**few XSLT stylesheets**](http://www.topxml.com/code/cod-422_9928_using-xslt-to-produce-svg-(3).aspx) published by Martin Rowlinson (Marrow) -- the author of XSelerator, back in 2002. You may find them on topxml.com, **but be warned that some people have alerted me that this site has a trojan on it -- therefore you should be equipped with good malware protection before clicking on the above link**!

Comment: Nice and maybe a tool for me to use if I have to roll my own SVG, but I was hoping to someone had done the math for me already.

Answer (score 0):

Found [chartSVG](http://hardcoded.net/chartsvg/).