# SVG chart generation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, charts, svg

I'm looking for a way to generate pie charts using SVG.

The numbers I have are simple enough - just percentages, an array of numbers that obviously add up to 100.

I have a basic understanding of SVG, but I can't think how to translate these numbers into meaningful coordinates to use in the path tag

Can anyone point me to a useful utility or library, or give any hints as to how I could use percentages to draw a pie chart - in JavaScript?

Comment: Related (but not duplicates): [SVG vs Canvas for pie charts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936474/pie-bar-line-svg-vml-better-than-canvas); [SVG pie charts using Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358390/svg-piechart-with-ruby); [XSLT lib for SVG charts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504130/looking-for-a-library-of-xslt-to-create-svg-charts).

Answer (score 17):

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3642265/309483 and http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/creating-a-svg-pie-chart-html5/ (note that the last one has a bug, fixed here)

```js
function makeSVG(tag, attrs) {
    var el= document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
    for (var k in attrs)
        if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(k)) el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
    return el;
}

function drawArcs(paper, pieData){
    var total = pieData.reduce(function (accu, that) { return that + accu; }, 0);
    var sectorAngleArr = pieData.map(function (v) { return 360 * v / total; });

    var startAngle = 0;
    var endAngle = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<sectorAngleArr.length; i++){
        startAngle = endAngle;
        endAngle = startAngle + sectorAngleArr[i];

        var x1,x2,y1,y2 ;

        x1 = parseInt(Math.round(200 + 195*Math.cos(Math.PI*startAngle/180)));
        y1 = parseInt(Math.round(200 + 195*Math.sin(Math.PI*startAngle/180)));

        x2 = parseInt(Math.round(200 + 195*Math.cos(Math.PI*endAngle/180)));
        y2 = parseInt(Math.round(200 + 195*Math.sin(Math.PI*endAngle/180)));

        var d = "M200,200  L" + x1 + "," + y1 + "  A195,195 0 " + 
                ((endAngle-startAngle > 180) ? 1 : 0) + ",1 " + x2 + "," + y2 + " z";
        //alert(d); // enable to see coords as they are displayed
        var c = parseInt(i / sectorAngleArr.length * 360);
        var arc = makeSVG("path", {d: d, fill: "hsl(" + c + ", 66%, 50%)"});
        paper.appendChild(arc);
        arc.onclick = (function (originalData) { 
          return function(event) {
            alert("Associated pie piece data: " + originalData);
          }
        })(pieData[i]);
    }
}
var svgdoc = document.getElementById("s");
drawArcs(svgdoc, [52,15,20,80]); // here is the pie chart data

// You can attach additional content (from e.g. AJAX) like this:
var parser = new DOMParser();
var docToEmbed = parser.parseFromString(
  "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><text x='50' y='50' fill='black'>hi</text></svg>", 
  "image/svg+xml");
Array.prototype.slice.call(docToEmbed.documentElement.childNodes).forEach(function(elem) {
  svgdoc.appendChild(document.importNode(elem, true));
});
```

```css
#con {
  resize:both;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  width:20em;
  height:20em;
  padding:0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="con">
<!-- the div container is of course optional. It is used with 
     {width,height}="100%" below to make the chart resizable. -->
<svg width="100%" height="100%" id="s"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 400 400">
  <style type="text/css">
    path:hover {
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
  </style>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Here are a few more:

- [Elycharts](http://elycharts.com/) (based on jQuery and Raphaël, MIT license)
- [ZingCharts](http://www.zingchart.com/#welcome) (commercial, has SVG/VML/HTML5/Flash backends)
- [Grafico](http://grafico.kilianvalkhof.com/index.html) (based on Prototype and Raphaël, MIT license)
- [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) (very nice library for interactive and dynamic graphs, MIT-like [license](https://raw.github.com/mbostock/d3/master/LICENSE))

I try to collect links to all svg graphing libraries [here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/links/search.php/all/graphs).

Comment: d3.js link is gone -> https://d3js.org/

Answer (score 3):

[Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) is a very good SVG drawing library -- in particular, it beats the others because in older versions of IE, it automatically falls back to using VML, and therefore it works in IE from version 6 and up, as well as in all other mainstream browsers.

It has a separate graphing library, called [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/). This does all the usual graph types (pies, lines, bars, etc), and can animate them too.

If those aren't enough, it's easy enough to use the main Raphael library to roll your own - it's very easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

The best (IMO): [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)

Others I have heard about:

- [PlotKit](http://www.liquidx.net/plotkit/)
- [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)